# sql - relation is unknown inside a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a relation that is built from 2 integers photo_id , user_id and a string -info, (this is the tag) , 
primary key is (user_id, photo_id, info)

```
photo_id | user_id | info 
---------------------------  
   5     |    3    |  aa
   7     |    6    |  aa
   2     |    2    |  bb
   1     |    2    |  cc
   1     |    9    |  aa
   2     |    8    |  cc
   1     |    4    |  cc
   9     |    9    |  cc
```

I'm trying to find the k most common tags in my relation. 
(secondary sort is by tags).
in this example i would like to get:

```
k=2 : aa , cc
k=1 : cc
```

By using this sql query :

```
SELECT info,tagCount  
FROM (SELECT info, COUNT(photo_id) as tagCount
      FROM Tags
      GROUP BY info 
      ORDER BY tagCount DESC, info ASC) T  
WHERE (SELECT count(info) FROM T T1 
       WHERE ((T1.tagCount > T.tagCount) OR
              (T1.tagCount = T.tagCount AND T1.info < T.info))) < 'k';
```

But I get the error:

> SQL error:
>
> ERROR:  relation "t" does not exist

Where is my mistake?

Comment: try changing 'SELECT count(info) FROM T T1' to 'SELECT count(info) tagCount FROM T1', 
It might be helpful to post the table structure with some sample data as well...

Comment: I have tried this, but now the error is: relation "t1" does not exist..
I've added more info about the table :)

Comment: by the way the order by clause in your subquery T is pointless

Comment: re: the error message. the alias t refers to an entire subquery, you cannot reuse that subquery for another subquery inside the where clause. Unless you use a common table expression (which isn't available in MySQL) or persist the subquery into a table.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in the where clause -- I think you are trying to do some cross join back to T?  Can't do that.

Comment: Are you using MySql or Sql Server? They are very different database engines, but the question has both tags. If you want to avoid downvotes here, you should tag the question for just the database type you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

While I still remain unclear on what you are trying to achieve, and assuming the query is for MySQL (not "sql server") then the following may also help. Please note that the cause of the error message is that alias T refers to a resultset, but you cannot reuse that entire resultset in the where clause (the subquery T1 assume that you can reuse T). Regrettablly MySQL (at the time of writing) does not support common table expressions which would allow referencing T like this:

```
/* T as a common table expression (CTE) */
with T as (
          SELECT info, COUNT(photo_id) as tagCount
          FROM Tags
          GROUP BY info 
          )
SELECT info,tagCount  
, (SELECT count(info) FROM T T1 
       WHERE (T1.tagCount > T.tagCount) OR
              (T1.tagCount = T.tagCount AND T1.info < T.info)
       ) as k
FROM  T  
ORDER BY tagCount DESC, info ASC
;
```

So, in the absence of a CTE capability, you have to repeat the initial subquery, like this:

```
SELECT
      info
    , tagCount
    , (
            SELECT
                  COUNT(info)
            FROM (
                  SELECT
                        info
                      , COUNT(photo_id) AS tagCount
                  FROM Tags
                  GROUP BY
                        info
            ) T1
            WHERE (T1.tagCount > T.tagCount)
                  OR (T1.tagCount = T.tagCount
                  AND T1.info < T.info)
      )
      AS k
FROM (
      SELECT
            info
          , COUNT(photo_id) AS tagCount
      FROM Tags
      GROUP BY
            info
) T
ORDER BY
      tagCount DESC
    , info     ASC
;
```

and the result of that query (from the sample data) is as follows:

```
| info | tagCount | k |
|------|----------|---|
|   cc |        4 | 0 |
|   aa |        3 | 1 |
|   bb |        1 | 2 |
```

Now, exactly how you derive the "expected result" shown in the question (where tag "bb" is not included) I remain unclear.

By the way. Another issue in your original query is that the where clause predicate is comparing an integer to 'k'

- where (select **count(info)** ....) < **'k'**

count(info) is an integer, 'k' is a string, so it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This may only be a step toward your solution as I don't completely understand the question. I think you need to count(distinct `column`) then use a much simpler where clause.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63aa5/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Tags
    (`photo_id` int, `user_id` int, `info` varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO Tags
    (`photo_id`, `user_id`, `info`)
VALUES
    (5, 3, 'aa'),
    (7, 6, 'aa'),
    (2, 2, 'bb'),
    (1, 2, 'cc'),
    (1, 9, 'aa'),
    (2, 8, 'cc'),
    (1, 4, 'cc'),
    (9, 9, 'cc')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      info
    , COUNT(distinct photo_id) AS photoCount
    , COUNT(distinct user_id) AS userCount
FROM Tags
GROUP BY
      info
ORDER BY
      photoCount DESC
    , userCount DESC
    , info     ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63aa5/1/0)**:

```
| info | photoCount | userCount |
|------|------------|-----------|
|   cc |          3 |         4 |
|   aa |          3 |         3 |
|   bb |          1 |         1 |
```